# MIMEText: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, html-email

I've got a bizarre problem drafting an email:

**python:**

```
def _create_draft(sender, to, subject, msg_html, msg_plain, attachments):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = to
    msg.attach(MIMEText(msg_plain, 'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(msg_html, 'html'))
    if attachments:
        msg = _add_attachments(msg, attachments)
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_bytes()).decode()}
```

`as_bytes` method above results in crash when trying to encode a list.

**Traceback:**

```
  File "/srv/www/code/project/email.py", line 56, in write_security_email
    send_message(from_address, to_address, subject, html_body, txt_body)
  File "/srv/www/code/project/gmail/gmail_api.py", line 52, in send_message
    msg = _create_draft(sender, to, subject, msgHtml, msgPlain, attachments)
  File "/srv/www/code/project/gmail/gmail_api.py", line 84, in _create_draft
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_bytes()).decode()}
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/message.py", line 178, in as_bytes
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 181, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 218, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/generator.py", line 431, in _handle_text
    if _has_surrogates(msg._payload) and not self.policy.cte_type=='7bit':
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/utils.py", line 57, in _has_surrogates
    s.encode()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

**Behaviour:**

- When I send just text it crashes as above. `msg_html` and `msg_plain` are strings, not lists. I replaced both with `"my string"`, same result. `attachments` variable is `None`.
- When I do send an atatchment, it sends and email with the attachment (but without body text) and does not crash
- When I comment the two `msg.attach` lines it sends email without the body
- before I added the attachment functionality this was sending the body just fine. I clearly changed something and forgot.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Worked a treat. I'm guessing attach doesn't work when you have attachment functionality with EmailMessage objects. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: As an aside, it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change from `attach` method to `set_content` and `add_alternative`. I'm guessing attach with text doesn't play well with attachments, not entirely sure. Anyway, works as below.

```
def _create_draft(sender, to, subject, msg_html, msg_plain, attachments):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = to
    msg.set_content(msg_plain)
    msg.add_alternative(msg_html, subtype='html')
    if attachments:
        msg = _add_attachments(msg, attachments)
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(msg.as_bytes()).decode()}
```

Thanks to @Michael Butscher and @Mokhless